# What mammalian species has the greatest relative variance in adult size?

Tags: zoology, natural-selection, mammals, measurement

The smallest adult chihuahuas weigh about 2 kg, and the largest adult English Mastiffs are around 104 kg, making them 52 times larger by weight.

Of course, this enormous variance is the result of selective breeding (i.e., artificial selection). What's the greatest variance, in relative terms, that has been observed in the *naturally* selected adults of a given mammalian species?  For example, are there any mammalian species for which it is possible to observe (in the wild) individual adults that differ in size (be it weight, height, length, or some other measure) by a factor of 50, or even 20 or 10?  Are there any environmental factors that might encourage such a large size variance within a species?

Comment: Is the difference between male and female individuals something you are interested in?  This is the biggest difference I am aware of, with elephant seal males being up to 10 times the size of females (from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_elephant_seal), females 400 to 900 kg males 2,200 to 4,000 kg)

Comment: If the greatest variance is from sexual dimorphism, then sure, that certainly counts. But in that case it would also be nice to know the greatest variance that _doesn't_ involve sexual dimorphism.

Comment: I bet you would like [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/biolinnean/article/70/4/571/2638643), about how much variation there is and why.  I do not think it answers your question exactly though.  [This paper](https://sci-hub.ru/https://doi.org/10.1007/s00265-002-0507-x) is about sexual dimorphism in pinnipeds like elephant seal.

Comment: Finding the most variable wild mammal in size is difficult because it is not usual (except the artificially selected breeds like dogs, horses, pigeons etc.). It is probably a small animal like a rodent species. I've found "variegated squirrel" as a promising candidate but the variation mostly comes in color, although [this paper](https://www.mammalsociety.org/uploads/2015%20ASM%20Abstracts%20Final-2015.05.05.pdf) talks about some morphological variety also. I've found the fish "arctic charr" as the most variable vertebrate (within most categories: size, phenotype, range, ecology etc.)

Comment: I tend to find [trivia-style questions](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3999/27148) to be not particularly useful contributions to this site, unless you can express some biologically interesting question to address with that trivia answer. The help asks that you [should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) - what's the actual problem to solve here?

Comment: If you're after trivia, the Guinness World of Records is great for individual specimens. [Jon Brower Minnoch](https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/heaviest-man) comes in at around 300 times heavier than [Lucia Xarate](https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/67485-lightest-person) in humans, for example.

Comment: Generally no - because you are essentially limited to clinal species (e.g. ring species) and the lack of ability to interbreed kind of limits the species definition. The only way a Chihuahua can breed with a Great Dane is artificially.... but I'll leave it to a better ecologist to answer.